# map function, recursively

Tags: haskell, recursion, map-function

So i have a function that takes in three variables. Variable y is called by another function that will turn it into a list.

I want to apply map to this list of variables. So that i can recurse through the function using all the elements of the list one at a time.

since this function takes in three variables, and one is a list that i want to recall the function and apply each element of the list until the list is empty. I am not sure how to do this and return the remaining two variables back each time.

```
search :: State -> Int -> Int -> Int 
search state n1 n2 = case n1 of 
  0 -> 1 * n2
  num -> average( map (search s) n1-1 n2)
     where s = turnStateToList s
```

i havent included the turn state to list but i dont think it is required to answer the question. basically it will produce a list of new states. think of it like a tree.

the errors i get are

```
* map is applied to too many functions 
* y has been given arguments however yy takes in 0 arguments
```

i understand how it is getting these errors however im not sure what else to do to fix it. Ive tried changing up the brackets and that just gives a different argument error.

Comment: `where y = anotherfunc y` mjakes no sense, since you define `y` in terms of `y`, so a recursive definition.

Comment: Frankly, _none_ of this makes much sense. Please give an example of how you actually hope to use `func` in practice. (And BTW, don't call functions `func`!)

Comment: "I want to apply map to variable y so that each time i call the function a different y value from the list of y is given." I am struggling to understand what it actually means. Can you show several examples of function input and desired output?

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for the help and feedback.

Comment: can you please include some inputs and the expected outputs? We have a hard time figuring out what you actually want to do and this could probably help a lot. As it is I really tried but have no clue what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments to your question, in Haskell you can define variables recursively, so `s = turnStateToList s` doesn't mean that you make a new `s` that gets the value of `turnStateToList` of the old s. Instead, it defines `s` recursively in terms of itself, which leads to the infinite expression `s = turnStateToList (turnStateToList (turnStateToList ...` which is probably not what you want.

To `map` over a list while keeping some arguments fixed you can introduce an anonymous function, in this case I think you want `\s'' -> search s'' (n1 - 1) n2` (the parentheses around `n1 - 1` are necessary!).

Oh, and I think you mixed up `state` and `s` by accident.

So, with minimal changes to your style, I think you want this code:

```hs
search :: State -> Int -> Int -> Int 
search s n1 n2 = case n1 of 
  0 -> 1 * n2
  num -> average( map (\s'' -> search s'' (n1 - 1) n2) s')
     where s' = turnStateToList s
```

I think it is more idiomatic to avoid the case statement and to avoid binding `turnStateToList s` to a variable, then you get this code:

```hs
search :: State -> Int -> Int -> Int
search _ 0  n2 = n2
search s n1 n2 = average $ map (\s' -> search s' (n1 - 1) n2) (turnStateToList s)
```